# How to filter categories in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a little problem. I want to create something like a webpages directory. In my model I've create a class Kategorie, and class Firma. Class Kategoria creating main categories and subcategories. In class Firma I can define in witch category and subcategory the new record will be belong. My question is: How to display in html on main page main categories and little lower the subcategories like in this picture
[image]

Here is my code
**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Kategoria(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Kategoria')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,verbose_name='Adres SEO')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('slug', 'parent',)
        verbose_name = 'Kategoria'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Kategorie'

    def __str__(self):
        full_path = [self.name]
        k = self.parent

        while k is not None:
            full_path.append(k.name)
            k = k.parent

        return ' / '.join(full_path[::-1])

class Firma(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, verbose_name='Użytkownik', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Nazwa firmy')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, verbose_name='Adres SEO')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Kategoria', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Kategoria', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name='Opis')
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Szablon')
    publish = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Firma'
        verbose_name_plural='Firmy'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Kategoria, Firma



def widok_kategorii(request):
    kategorie = Kategoria.objects.filter().order_by('name')
    context = {'kategorie': kategorie}
    return render(request, 'ogloszenia/index.html', context=context)
```

**index.html**

```
{% include 'ogloszenia/header.html' %}
Wyświetl kategorie<br>

{% for kategoria in kategorie %}
<b>{{kategoria.name}}<br></b>
{% endfor %}


{% include 'ogloszenia/footer.html' %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is sub categories, right?

You can use `inclusion_tag` in your template as i mentioned here once:
[Tree Structure (Foreign Keys to itself) and templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47051519/tree-structure-foreign-keys-to-itself-and-templates/)

If you need to render multiple level of sub categories then just do as i mentioned in the link.

But if you just need the first level, then it's pretty simple:

**views.py:**

Getting categories without any parent (line #2)

```
def widok_kategorii(request):
    ### Get the categories without any parent.
    kategorie = Kategoria.objects.filter(parent=None).order_by('name')
    context = {'kategorie': kategorie}
    return render(request, 'ogloszenia/index.html', context=context)
```

**Template:**

```
{% include 'ogloszenia/header.html' %}
Wyświetl kategorie<br>
<ul>
    {% for kategoria in kategorie %}
        <li>
            {{kategoria.name}}
            {% if kategoria.children.count > 0 %}
                <ul>
                    {% for sub in kategoria.children.all %}
                        <li>{{ sub.name }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>


{% include 'ogloszenia/footer.html' %}
```

You can just design it to be look like the picture you posted but this is the way to achive the tree structure for such a design.